# media query resizing of image on Android Gmail App not working

Tags: android, gmail, html-email, litmus

I am working on a responsive email, testing it in Litmus for Android 6.0 and on a Samsung Galaxy S7 physical device.

Here is my media query from the head style section:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 611px), screen and (max-device-width: 611px){
[class=devicewidth100]{width:100%!important; height:auto!important;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FFFFFF!important;}
[class=devicewidth98]{width:98%!important; height:auto!important;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FFFFFF!important;}
[class=devicewidth60]{width:60%!important; height:auto!important;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FFFFFF!important;}
[class=imgdevicewidth]{width:100%!important; height:auto!important; margin-left:auto!important; margin-right:auto!important;}
[class=hide]{display:none !important;}
[class=center]{text-align:center!important; padding-top:5px!important; padding-bottom:5px!important; height:auto!important;}
}
```

Here is HTML code from the body:

```html
<tr><td style="border-collapse: collapse;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr><td><![endif]-->
<div style="width: 185px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;height: auto!important;background-color: #FFFFFF!important;" class="devicewidth100">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;align-content: center;"><tr><td width="15" style="border-collapse: collapse;"></td><td width="170" class="devicewidth100" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 100%!important;height: auto!important;background-color: #FFFFFF!important;"><a href="#" style="color: #F4F4F4;text-decoration: none!important;"><img src="http://placehold.it/810x456" alt="" style="border: none;display: block;outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 100%!important;height: auto!important;background-color: #FFFFFF!important;" width="170" height="125" class="devicewidth100"></a></td><td width="15" style="border-collapse: collapse;"></td></tr></table></div><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td><td><![endif]-->
<div style="width: 430px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;height: auto!important;background-color: #FFFFFF!important;" class="devicewidth100">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;align-content: center;">
<tr><td width="15" style="border-collapse: collapse;"></td><td align="left" class="center" style="text-align: left;border-collapse: collapse;padding-top: 5px!important;padding-bottom: 5px!important;height: auto!important;" height="125" valign="middle"><a href="#" style="font-family:'Open Sans', verdana; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; color:#000000; line-height:22px; text-align:left; text-decoration:none;" class="fontsize-top-news">This is my text, it should get bigger on mobile screens at some point.</a></td></tr>
</table></div>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></td></tr>
```

I am trying to make the image full-width with the media query. Since Litmus and the Galaxy S7 Gmail App are supposed to have CSS/Media Query support now, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a device to test, so it would only be a guess but I would try in the standard css notation:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 611px), screen and (max-device-width: 611px){
    .devicewidth100{
        width:100%!important; 
        height:auto!important;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto; 
        background-color:#FFFFFF!important;
    }
    .devicewidth98{
        width:98%!important; 
        height:auto!important;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto; 
        background-color:#FFFFFF!important;
    }
    .devicewidth60{
        width:60%!important; 
        height:auto!important;
        margin-left:auto; 
        margin-right:auto; 
        background-color:#FFFFFF!important;
    }
    .imgdevicewidth{
        width:100%!important;
        height:auto!important;
        margin-left:auto!important;
        margin-right:auto!important;
    }
    .hide{
        display:none !important;
    }
    .center{
        text-align:center!important;
        padding-top:5px!important;
        padding-bottom:5px!important;
        height:auto!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, Niklas is correct. Gmail does not support attribute selector CSS (https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2016/10/gmail-update-googles-rendering-refresh/) - also, some clients in Android STILL do not have the rollout.

Comment: @Gortonington I found this post recently: https://twitter.com/cygro/status/816633313364475904 It's a chart from Cyrill Gross showing what supports what. It always helps me when troubleshooting

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for the resource

Comment: Thank you for replying, but it didn't help. For images and table elements I still leave the as `class="devicewidth100"` correct? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user3314426 What are you sending with? Also maybe try to include both notations. Also maybe try to leave out the screen. I always just use min- and max-width.

Comment: I was testing in Litmus, which I thought had the latest version of the Android 6.0 Gmail app that allegedly supports media queries now, but apparently that is not the case according to other people I've asked, so it looks like I cannot rely on Litmus or my Samsung phone to have the correct Gmail App update yet.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend from what client you are using. Not all versions of gmail App support media queries yet.

Gmail Android app (POP/IMAP account) will not support media queries.

You can find the full list here:

[Gmail Rolls Out Support for Responsive Design, Improved Font Styling + CSS for Accessibility](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design)